# GCP Dataflow throws exception Shuffle key too large

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a piece of code that groups my data but it throws an exception when I do output.

This class is used as key in KV

```
class CKey {
    private Long id;
    private Long subId;
}
```

It's part of my Dataflow job

```
TupleTag<CItem> itemsTuple = //...
TupleTag<CMeta> metaTuple = //...

//...

PCollection<KV<CKey, CItem>> items = null;
PCollection<KV<CKey, CMeta>> meta;

KeyedPCollectionTuple.of(itemsTuple, items).and(metaTuple, meta.next())
        .apply(CoGroupByKey.create())
        .apply(new CustomGroupPairsFn());
```

Custom function to join data

```
class CustomGroupPairsFn extends DoFn<KV<CKey, CoGbkResult>, MyCustomObject> {

        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(@Element KV<CKey, CoGbkResult> element, OutputReceiver<MyCustomObject> out) {
            CoGbkResult pair = element.getValue();
            Iterator<CItem> citem = pair.getAll(ITEMS).iterator();
            Iterator<CMeta> cmeta = pair.getAll(METADATA).iterator();
            try {
                out.output(new MyCustomObject(citem.next(), cmeta));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Error occurred", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

There is only 1 line of code in `try` and exception is thrown inside, exception:

[image]

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Can you tell more about your pipeline? Is there a GroupByKey around there somewhere? Is it streaming? Or batch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens because you're shuffling a key that is too large.

**What does this mean?** In Dataflow, the largest shuffle key allowed is 1.5 MB for streaming pipelines. You seem to have an element key that is larger than that.

Perhaps your pipeline has a GroupByKey/Shuffling operation somewhere unexpected, so that's why it would be great to have more details about it.

Comment: There is a `CoGroupByKey.create()` in my pipeline, what this key consists of and when the shuffling is done and why?

Comment: I found that `GroupByKey.create()` is used inside of `CoGroupByKey.create()`. But how can I changed the size of key?

Comment: Can you share more info about your pipeline? Is it streaming or batch? What operations are downstream and upstream from the ParDo you mention? The Key is, technically, the Key in a KV-pair. Shuffling is when data is serialized and passed around workers in your pipeline...

Comment: It's a batch job. I've updated the code in a question.

Comment: does only key size of KV cause this issue or both key and value of KV effects the size?

Comment: only the key is what matters. but the value may be made into a key in other operators (e.g. Distinct)

Comment: Yes, the problem was in `Distinct `